# Inconsistent loop execution times with large memory processing

Tags: python, performance, loops, debugging, memory

I have numerous large csv files (~400 MB each, need to process thousands of them, at least a hundred per program execution) containing long strings in the first cell of each row (about 100-300 characters per row for 1 million rows per file), and my Python program checks if a substring is in a given string. If so, then I append the row containing the string to a list, to be stored in another series of csv files after all the input files have been processed. For the first dozen input files, the program runs at about 20 seconds per file, which I am satisfied with.

The relevant portion of the code (the string-processing loop) looks as such:

```
check = set(['a','b','c'])
storage = []
data = glob.glob('data_address/*.csv')
for raw_file in data:
    read_file = open(raw_file,'r',newline='',encoding='utf-8')  
    list_file = list(csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in read_file), delimiter=","))
    row_count = sum(1 for row in list_file)

    for i in range(1, row_count);
        text = set(list_file[i][0].split())
        if len(check.intersection(text)) > 0:
           storage.append(list_file[i])
```

The problem is that as the number of processed input files grows, I begin to have certain files that take much longer than 20 seconds. Furthermore, these anomalies take longer and longer to process - the first anomaly takes about 50 seconds to process, and towards the end of the loop, anomalies can take thousands of seconds to process, suggesting that the problem is with the loop itself rather than any individual file. These anomalies are not obviously different from the other files in terms of number of string matches.

What I don't understand is that the increase in processing time is not consistent. I still have plenty of 20-second files in between each anomaly, so it cannot be that the program is simply slowing down as memory storage increases. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? cProfile fails to show any component that might be causing the issue.

I use 64-bit Python 3.8 on Windows 10 with a 1TB hard drive, with about 10,000 MB active memory.

Comment: @barny Thank you for your feedback. I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: In the code you shared you aren't closing the file. You should really use context managers, they're great. Can you provide a [mcve]? I can see some things which could be refactored, but it's tough to do when I can't run the code. Also, while it may not explain the particular issue at hand, there are many inefficient aspects to this code.

Comment: That’s a rather unusual way of using csv. Have you tried a more conventional approach? Look at the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html. But if it’s specific files that have a problem then the generic code *isn’t* the problem: , what’s different about those files?

Comment: Someone, apparently ‘god’-like, deleted my comment: show yourself, ‘god’: why did you do that?

Comment: @amc although i agree the OP should use `with`, the file will be closed each time round the loop when `read_file` is assigned a new open file. What’s more likely to be the problem is that `list_file` is referenced by storage and that will only grow memory usage.

Comment: What does ‘large’ mean? Be specific. And what does ‘long’ mean? Be specific.

Comment: And you still haven’t been specific about whether you are using 32- or 64-bit OS & Python, and how much memory your computer has.

Comment: @barny Thanks, I've further edited my post

Comment: @AMC I'm afraid it's hard to produce a reproducible example because this is really about the size of the files and number of loops

Comment: @pythonuser Sorry if my comment wasn’t clear, I meant an example to reproduce the functioning of the program, not the performance issue.

Comment: Please elaborate on ‘large’ and ‘long’

Comment: @barny Hi, I've elaborated on 'large' and 'long' in parentheses beside those adjectives.

Comment: And ‘few’? And how many rows of a file are matched in the ‘specific’ files that take longer to process? Where you put a vague adjective, be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't yet have enough information to properly diagnose the issue, so in the meantime I thought I would try to improve the code you shared:

```py
import csv
import pathlib

check = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

data_path = pathlib.Path("data_address")

saved_rows = []

for curr_path in data_path.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(curr_path, newline='') as curr_file:
        reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0', '') for line in curr_file), delimiter=",")

        for row in reader:
            row_text = row[0].split()
            if any(elem in check for elem in row_text):
                saved_rows.append(row)
```

Although I'm not able to test it, it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly and actually solved my problem! Now I'm getting ~20s per file throughout.

Comment: @pythonuser Which is what you were getting for the iterations before the performance issues, right? So it's a constant ~20s now?